# How to fix a program that doesn't perform the same on other platforms?

Tags: c

This code is working well in my phone, but when I used this code on Quincy 2005, its output is far different from the correct output. Please help me in this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int totalBooks, soldBooks[7], sum, unsoldPercentage;

    char days[7] = { 'S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S' };
    char Days[7] = { 'u', 'o', 'u', 'e', 'h', 'r', 'a' };
    char dayS[7] = { 'n', 'n', 'e', 'd', 'u', 'i', 't' };

    printf("Enter the quantity of all books you have: ");
    scanf("%d", &totalBooks);

    int j = 0, k = 0, l = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("%c%c%c: ", days[j++], Days[k++], dayS[l++]);
        scanf("%d", &soldBooks[i]);

        sum += soldBooks[i];
    }

    unsoldPercentage = (totalBooks - sum) * 100 / totalBooks;

    printf("%d%% of books are unsold.", unsoldPercentage);
}
```

Considering the inputs:

100(totalBooks) 5*7((35)books sold for the whole week). I expect the output to be "65% of books are unsold.", yet in Quincy 2005 I got a 6-digit number, and that is wrong.

Comment: If `scanf` fails, you’re using uninitialized values. Check its return value each time you use it. `if (scanf("%d", &thing) != 1) { /* problem */ }`. Since `unsoldPercentage` is wrong, did you use a debugger/more `printf`s to check what was going into its calculation?

Comment: Why don't you use one and the same `i` for all your indexing, as j, k and l will be equal to i anyway?

Comment: A bit easier would have been: `char const* days[] = { "Mon", "Tue", /* ... */};` and having `printf("%s", days[i])`.

Comment: This is really some weird piece of code.

Answer (score 4):

`sum` is not initialised to 0, so when you do `sum += soldBooks[i]`, you are adding to some undefined number (undefined behaviour) the soldBooks of each day, so you are getting an unknown number.

Being *undefined behaviour*, you can observe differences between different platforms and compilers.
This is why you are seeing the expected value with one platform (where the compiler does automatically initialise the variables to 0) and unexpected values in other platforms (where the compiler does not do this initialisation).

You cannot rely on *undefined behaviour* on any platform, despite showing the correct value, since this may be just a lucky test, or it may change with different compiler versions, etc...

And finally, you should compile your program enabling all warnings. The compiler should have emitted a warning, something like: *"Reading from an unitialised variable*".

Answer (score 3):

`sum` is not initialized. Yet you are adding to it new values so the result is undefined.
Set `sum=0;` at the very beginning.